How to generate pdf file using Rotativa NuGet package?
I want to generate pdf file in class library.
I want to generate a view to pdf. I use Rotative for this ,but i need ControllerContext.
   var pdf=  new Rotativa.UrlAsPdf("my url");
   var bytes = pdf.BuildFile(new ControllerContext());
   var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(bytes);

How to generate pdf file in class library?
How to generate pdf file in class library?

in class livrary i dont have ControllerContext for use rotative

This library provides a quick way to print Html to Pdf on Windows using the WebView control. You can generate Pdf from Html of a Url or file by using a few different mechanisms
var host = new HtmlToPdfHost();
var pdfPrintSettings = new WebViewPrintSettings()
{
 Orientation = WebViewPrintOrientations.Landscape,
};
var url =  "MyUrl";
var stream = host.PrintToPdfStreamAsync(url , pdfPrintSettings);
var memoryStream = stream.Result.ResultStream;

memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

